# How to calculate sum of vector subspaces

Tags: vector-spaces, direct-sum

How do you sum these given subspaces? $$S_1=\{(x,y) \in R^2 | x=y\}$$$$S_2=\{(x,y) \in R^2 | x=-y\}$$
The book that I am currently learning from gives the answer to be $R^2$, but how do you get there?

Why does $S_1+S_2=R^2$? It also says that the sum is a direct one. What does that mean?

Similarly, for $S_3=\{(x,y) \in R^2 | 3x-2y=0\}$ and $S_4=\{(x,y) \in R^2 | 2x-y=0\}$, how do you show that $S_3 \oplus S_4=R^2$? The $\oplus$ from what I understand means that this is a direct sum (although I don't know what that is). The problems seem the same. Is it just a matter of writing $x$ in terms of $y$ for both $S_3$ and $S_4$ and nothing more? I guess if I will understand the first one, I will be able to understand the second one, too.

Also, I should point out that I know a little about linear combinations and linear independence, and I found somewhere that you can solve it with those, but I am at a chapter before the one with linear combinations in the book, so I think it can be solved without them. If not, I will be satisfied with any explanation. And please excuse my possible English mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $S_1$ is generated by $b_1=(1,1)$ and $S_2$ by $b_2=(1,-1)$ and both are linearly independent in $\Bbb R^2$ then $S_1+S_2=\Bbb R^2$.

For $S_3$ the restriction $3x-2y=0$ implies that 
$$(x,y)=(x,\frac{3}{2}x)$$ 
after solving for $y$. The geometrical meaning is a parameterization (in terms of $x$) of a line which passes through the origin. This is you subspace $S_3$ and is generated by any nonzero vector therein. I chose $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: $b_1$ and $b_2$ are linearly independent because if you take a linear combination $k^1b_1+k^2b_2$ which is equal to the zero vector then it is easy to deduce that $k^1=k^2=0$

Comment: So for the second example I would choose $b_1=(1,\frac{2}{3})$ and $b_2=(1, \frac{1}{2})$, and apply the same reasoning? And what does the direct sum mean?

Comment: well, for the second $b_1=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2})$ and $b_2=(\frac{1}{2},1)$ are generator for $S_1$ and $S_2$ respectively. And yes, both $S_1+S_2=\Bbb R^2$ and $S_1\oplus S_2=\Bbb R^2$ are symbols for the direct sum.

Comment: the components of $b_1$ and $b_2$ should comply with the definitions of $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Comment: My mistake: I named the second example subspaces $S_3$ and $S_4$, but I forgot and named the vectors $b_1$ and $b_2$ when I should have used $b_3$ and $b_4$ to make it more clear. Anyway: I see you found $(\frac {1}{3}, \frac {1}{2})$ and $(\frac {1}{2}, 1)$ to be the generators. My question is now: how do you find the generators for a subspace like this?

Comment: any election of a nonzero $x$ determines a $y$, which for the kind of all your $S_i$, going to give you a generator of each.

Comment: Could you be a little more precise, please, and do it step by step for the second example? I don't really understand and I guess it is because English is not my native language, and also because I am a beginner in linear algebra.

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks :)

Comment: if doubts persist - don't hesitate asking